# sklearn; Value of hyperparameters are the same before and after model fitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, model-fitting

I would like to check the value of hyperparameters of a scikit-learn model before and after fitting:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4, n_informative=2, n_redundant=0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)

print(clf.get_params())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(clf.get_params())
```

It gives me the same value before and after model fitting. I thought that hyperparameters should be different after model fitting. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, when I want to use model for prediction, what are the hyperparameters that model use for prediction?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hyperparameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_(machine_learning)) are part of the configuration of the learning algorithm (RandomForestClassifier in the example) and do not change during the training process. The output result of get_params() shows the model's hyperparameter configuration. The internal state of the model (i.e. the node definitions in the decision trees that comprise the random forest) do change during model training, but that information is not provided by get_params().

Comment: Thank you. When I use cross-validation, should I initialize model internal state (or model weights) in every fold?

Comment: Cross-validation is about varying the dataset in each fold and does not prescribe anything about the model's internal state. But if changing the initialization helps for your particular application, maybe it's worthwhile. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352253/should-i-use-the-same-weight-initialization-for-each-fold-in-cross-validation) is a related discussion on another stack exchange.